# set NODE_ENV variable in production via docker file

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use below code below code in nodejs

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
```

I tried to set NODE_ENV variable from docker file like below.

```
FROM collinestes/docker-node-oracle:10-slim
ENV NODE_ENV=production
EXPOSE  8085
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

If i to run my docker image it does not start and throws error. If i remove NODE_ENV all runs fine. Is it the right way to setting NODE_ENV from dockerfile?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 14):

Remove the equal sign

```
ENV NODE_ENV production
```

Comment: But i have other variables like ENV UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=5 which does not have any issue.

Comment: Syntax is not the problem in this case, `ENV` supports both styles as shown in here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Answer (score 4):

Your Dockerfile should work, are you sure there isn't anything else inside the application, maybe package.json could be override it ?

I have tested it and it works correctly

```
$ echo $NODE_ENV
production
```

Also I would suggest to set the `NODE_ENV` variable while running the container as it would be easier to modify, I am aware that you can override it anyway if needed but setting it on the run-time will make your image with less layers. you can use the command below

> -e can be used to pass an environment variable and can be passed multiple times if you have more than one variable

```
docker run -e NODE_ENV=production $IMAGENAME
```

Comment: npm start has babel-node --presets es2015 index.js and when i have that variable in docker file it throws up error like babel-node not found

Comment: So maybe you need to configure `PATH` to make it work. This is just my guessing as I don't know more information about your actual Dockerfile

Comment: If i use prod instead of production, it works fine.

Comment: So it seems  your application uses `prod` not `production`, am i correct ?

Comment: Yeah. So i had to change my code also top prod. If i use production in dockerfile, it does not work.

Comment: I changed in docker file and code also to prod and all worked fine.

Comment: I cannot tell without knowing the framework. have you reviewed the framework's documentation or github issues ? maybe they have something special regarding the node env variable ?

Comment: Using AWS ECS Docker instances, I ended up adding an Environment Variable in the Task Definition key NODE_ENV and value production. Things worked fine. Somehow I stumbled onto this page with my issue, so documenting it for others.